# Change data-center using WTelegramClient

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

Using `WTelegramClient` library, How should I get the list of available telegram data-centers and select another DC?

Link to Telegram API DC descriptions:
https://core.telegram.org/api/datacenter

Comment: you can pass the `server_address` parameter in your config with the desired IP address

Answer (score 2):

Once connected, you can look at `client.TLConfig.dc_options` for the available data centers.

However you cannot change DC because a user account is tied to a specific DC and is only allowed to call APIs from that DC (except for file transfers)

So even if you connect to a different DC, once you try to login as a user, Telegram will ask you to reconnect to the correct DC for this user. (WTelegramClient will do this switch automatically)

Comment: If logout and then relogin, DC would change? Or it will be same as last session?

Comment: @HamidZ no dc would be set once you create your account and it will be the same until you delete your account, note that you can change to a test DC any time you want, but the actual production DC will not allow you to do that

Comment: DC is typically linked to your phone number international country code. So it won't change for as long as the phone number isn't changed.

Comment: @Wizou how can I find client's current DC and its IP?

Comment: `client.TLConfig.this_dc` but you really shouldn't have to worry about that. WTelegramClient handles all of this automatically for you.